# If $\frac{|z-a|}{|z-b|}=c$ for a constant $c$ not equal to $1$, then prove that the expression is a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

I saw a similar question which asked to show that the locus traced out by $arg(\frac{z-a}{z-b})=c$ is a circle.  I know how to prove that but what is the connection between the $2$ questions.  Can I describe the equation $\frac{z-a}{z-b}=c$ by its argument?

Also, how do I find the radius and centre of the equation?

Thanks

Comment: Square both sides and turn it into a quadratic polynomial in $x,y$. Then the discriminant tells you which conic section you got.

Comment: There are *two* questions under the `related` column on the right hand side of this page which have answers that apply here. Also see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218133/proving-the-apollonian-circle-formula/2218323), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296382/describing-apollonian-circle-and-locus-of-set-of-points-in-complex-plane) among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\frac{|z-a|}{|z-b|}=c.$$

Let $z=x+iy$ and $a=a_1+ia_2$, $b=b_1+ib_2.$

We have $$(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2= c^2(x-b_1)^2+c^2(y-b_2)^2$$

$$ (1-c^2)x^2 + ( 1-c^2)y^2 -2(a_1-c^2 b_1)x-2(a_2-c^2 b_2)y+a_1^2+b_2^2-c^2b_1^2-c^2b_2^2=0$$

Which is the equation of a circle if the constant $  a_1^2+b_2^2-c^2 b_1^2-c^2 b_2^2$ is negative.

The center and the radius could easily be found.